# Plot histogram in R

Tags: r, plot

Given the following data frame:

```
 time       frequency
0000 - 0059 8
0100 - 0159 4
0200 - 0259 17
0300 - 0359 5
0400 - 0459 71
0500 - 0559 477
0600 - 0629 325
0630 - 0659 661
0700 - 0714 558
0715 - 0729 403
0730 - 0744 671
0745 - 0759 444
0800 - 0814 641
0815 - 0829 356
0830 - 0844 427
```

need to plot a a histogram of 15 bins, where x is labelled with the "time" for each bin and y is titled with "frequency". Is there a good way to make it?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `?barplot`?

Comment: `barplot(df$frequency, names.arg = df$time, las = 2)`

Comment: @d.b the "time" intervals in the data aren't equally sized...

Comment: If that "frequency" is a count, do you want the bars for the wider time periods scaled appropriately? Can you draw a picture of what you want? What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I need it can be scaled appropriately."efficient" just mean a quick way to plot such a figure.

Comment: Why not a time series plot?